# Razor syntax in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

I am converting the following code present in webform (DemoView.aspx) to razor view (DemoView.cshtml)

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#listDetails").click(function () { location.href = "<%= Model.ListDetailsUrl %>"; });

            $("#provideDetails").validate({
                rules: {
                    <% bool isFirst=true; foreach (var q in Model.Details) { if (!isFirst) { %>,<% }; isFirst=false; %>
                        "answer-<%= q.SequenceNumber %>": {
                            required: true
                            <% if (q.ValueType == Demo.ValueType.Int) { %>,digits: true<% } %>
                            <% if (q.ValueType == Demo.ValueType.Decimal) { %>,number: true<% } %>
                        }
                    <% } %>
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But I am getting errors while conversion.

Can any one help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: You have to use MVC 3 to use Razor syntax. Strongly suggest you upgrade your project to a later version (MVC 5 is the current latest and quite amazing).

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC3. I am converting the application from ASP.NET MVC2 TO ASP.NET MVC3.

Comment: Wow, talk about your mixed problem domains! Consider refactoring to provide your rules as JSON from a service call, or even serializing a model object into JSON, rather than kludging it together inside the jQuery call. It will make it easier to debug in the future and make it also less brittle of an implementation. What you have there is like an old school Classic ASP nightmare come back to life...